# Server error when trying to view an old deleted user as a mod

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, deleted-accounts, 500-server-error

When I try to visit a specific deleted user stub, it tries to load for a while and then gives an error. At least it was, and now it's just taking about 3 seconds to load, which seems unusually long. I also noticed that the meta version, which has always loaded near-instantly and without any 500 errors, does not have exactly the same information!

- Error: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/19341/

  Shows which staff member deleted the user, but has their old username (the one they used in 2013). This is not perfect but it's unambiguous who it was thanks to the ID.
- No error: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19341

  Username and ID are missing entirely:

  > User: Please Delete Me (19341) deleted by **Anonymous (0)**

There are some deleted user stubs from around the same time that also take a few seconds to load, but I didn't find any that had these specific problems (500 error and discrepancy in the deleting user) nor any others with a meta stub that were deleted by this staff member (or another with a name change) during this time period.

Comment: We can't update display names on those pages. That log message is generated and stored as plain-text at the time of deletion. As well, we didn't start sending the moderator Id to the meta deletion until ~2015 so that information just didn't exist when that log was created. // Not sure what could be causing the load issues though.